# Get all values to a numeric value

Tags: python, pandas

As you can see my df contains a price list with values like `$106.00` and `'1,190.00`. I want to get the values to a numeric value. So I want to replace the $ sign. But that didn't work.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'price':['$106.00', '$156.00',
'$166.00', '$106.00', '1,190.00']})
    
df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.price.str.replace("$",""))
# df['price'] = pd.to_numeric(df.price.str[1:])
# that givs me a ValueError: Unable to parse string "1,925.00" at position 7765
```

What I want at the end

```
ID price
A  106.00
B  156.00
C  166.00
D  106.00
E  1,190.00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `regex` and replace `'\$'` and `','` with `''` then convert to numeric like below: *(we use `'|'` for search `$` or `,`)*

```
>>> df.price = pd.to_numeric(df.price.str.replace(r"\$|,","", regex=True))
>>> df

    id  price
0   A   106.0
1   B   156.0
2   C   166.0
3   D   106.0
4   E   1190.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this. Using regex substitute all the non-digit values with '' and then convert it to decimal. Apply this for all values in 'price' list

```
import pandas as pd
from re import sub
from decimal import Decimal

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'price':['$106.00', '$156.00',
'$166.00', '$106.00', '1,190.00']})
    
df['price']=df['price'].apply(lambda x: Decimal(sub(r'[^\d.]', '', x)))
print(df)
```

output

```
id    price
0  A   106.00
1  B   156.00
2  C   166.00
3  D   106.00
4  E  1190.00
```